# Firefox for Android content provider?

Tags: android, firefox, android-contentprovider

Can somebody give me an example on how could I use the Firefox for Android content provider for getting a list of the links in my app history?

Thanks!

Comment: I was under the impression that Firefox content providers were not exported, meaning they are not usable from third-party apps. If you have evidence to the contrary, please link to it.

Comment: After a few quick searches i found this blog post that gave me the impression that this can be done: http://lucasr.org/2012/05/21/native-firefox-for-android-beta/

Comment: You are right! I think I "skipped"the private part! Sorry!

Comment: Also - do you have any ideea on how I could get a list of links from the Firefox app? A workaround maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox's `ContentProvider` is not accessible to third party applications. Here is the permission declaration from the [manifest](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/base/AndroidManifest.xml.in#375):

```
<permission android:name="@ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME@.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

A `protectionLevel` of `"signature"` means that the permission is only available to apps that are signed with the same key. Unless they change this, there's no way for your app to access the `ContentProvider`.