# Get firefox browser history in android

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, browser-history

I am using this uri `Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI` to access default browser history and this uri `content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks` to access chrome browser history in my android app. But I am not able to get Firefox browser history. Can any one help ?

Comment: I think Link will help you since you want to access firefox browser history 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453587/firefox-for-android-content-provider

Comment: @Kartheek, this link is for desktop version. I wanted to display the history of Firefox browser (app) in my android app. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @XAlchemist, this link is not related to my question. Thanks for your help.